# How to manage catches with the same behavior

Tags: java, exception

I have a piece of code that can throw three different types of exceptions. Two of these exceptions are handled in a certain way while the third is handled in another way. Is there a good idiom for not cutting and pasting in this manner?

What I would like to do is:

```
try { anObject.dangerousMethod(); }
catch {AException OR BException e) { /*do something*/ }
catch {CException e) { /*do something else*/ }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [in JDK 7](http://extreme-java.blogspot.com/2011/05/jdk-7-multi-catch-blocks-for-exceptions.html), but not in earlier Java versions. In JDK 7 your code could look like this:

```
try { anObject.dangerousMethod(); }
catch {AException | BException e) { /*do something*/ }
catch {CException e) { /*do something else*/ }
```

Answer (score 3):

As defined by new Java 7 specifications you can now have.

```
try { anObject.dangerousMethod(); }
catch {AException | BException e) { /*do something*/ }
catch {CException e) { /*do something else*/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 6 doesn't support specifying catch blocks this way. Your best bet would be to define a super-class/interface for those two exception types and catch the super-class/interface. Another simple solution would be to have a method which contains the logic for handling those two exceptions and call that method in the two catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a custom Exception (let's say `DException`) that extends both `AException` and `BException`, then use it in your code:

```
try { anObject.dangerousMethod(); }
catch {DException e) { /*do something*/ }
catch {CException e) { /*do something else*/ }
```

Comment: Err, I guess you meant `DException` which both `AException` and `BException` extend.